# error x is not a function when calling method

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to run the following code but all I get is **Error: str.stringSplit is not a function**

```
const str = '7The quick 8brown jhbjhb 78646845fox jum56ps.';

function stringSplit(str, delimiter) {
   var substrings = [];

   if (delimiter === '') {
      for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
         substrings.push(str[i]);
      }
      return substrings;
   }
}

console.log(str.stringSplit(7));
```

Comment: `stringSplit()` is not an extension method, you have to call it this way : `stringSplit(str, '7')`

Comment: @Cid never heard about extension methods term, yet that returns **undefined**

Comment: Debugging your function is now another topic

Comment: is there a way to determine whether a function is extension method or not ? @Cid

Comment: What is that function meant to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way to call your function:

```js
console.log(stringSplit(str,7));
```

or you can create a prototype in this way:

```js
String.prototype.stringSplit = function(delimiter) {
  var substrings = [];

   if (delimiter === '') {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
         substrings.push(this[i]);
      }
   }
   return substrings;
};
const str = '7The quick 8brown jhbjhb 78646845fox jum56ps.';
console.log(str.stringSplit(7));
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can read from your post is a misunderstanding of how JavaScript works. From what you're trying to achieve I think there is already a built in method from JavaScript CORE such as [split from the String prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

By using this syntax after calling a function:

```
str.stringSplit(7) // You are actually calling a function that should exist on the Prototype of the String primitive
```

It's very important to know what you want to obtain... Do you want to split the string using a separator ? Do you want to learn how the prototype works ? Usually altering the prototype with methods like this it's not best practice since it can name collide with other existing functions and before creating one check the MDN docs if maybe there isn't an existing method that achieve's what you want.

The verified answer provides an valid example of how to add a method to the String prototype and if you want to call your function simply use this syntax (the name of the function followed by curly braces and add in the braces the params you'd like to use)

```
stringSplit(stringFoo, numberHere)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, indeed I was misleading how strings works in **js**. Thanks to the answers, I've got that only built in methods can be acceded using this syntax `nameOfString.methodName()` else I have to add the function to the string prototype or to pass the string as an argument.